# Fibonacci sequence: can understand the code

Tags: ruby, yield

Fibonacci sequence is 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ... The first two elements are 1. Each successive element is the sum of previous two elements.

I have problem understanding the code below. I understand that `i1, i2 = i2, i1+i2` will return `1, 1, 2, ...`, but how come it returns `..., 3, 5, 8, ...`? `i1, i2 = 1, 1` is specified; where does this `3` come from? If I understand this, I think I will understand why it becomes `5, 8, ...`.

```
def fib_to(max)
  i1,i2 = 1,1
  while i1 <= max
    yield i1
    i1, i2 = i2, i1+i2
  end
end

fib_to(100) do |f| 
  #yeild(i1) is replaced by this |f|?
  puts f
end
```

result

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
```

Comment: Do you even know what Fibonacci sequence is?

Comment: @sawa Let's try to keep tone in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Try to think about what numbers are stored in `i1` and `i2`, and what happens to them at each step. At each step, the value of `i2` gets overwritten into `i1`, and the value that was stored in `i2` gets incremented by the value stored in `i1`. At each step, you return the value stored in `i1`.

You start with `1, 1` (and return 1), then you get `1, 2` (and return 1), then you get `2, 3` (and return 2), then you get `3, 5` (and return 3) and so on.

Comment: This is the part I don't understand!!  You say the value is stored in "i1", but where is this code?   You start with 1, 1 (and return 1), but next you will get "1, 1, 2", because the code is "i1, i2 = i2, i1+i2"?? Why does this "i1" become "2, 3, 5..."??

Comment: @macjeans When Asad says things like "you get 1,1" and "you get 1,2", he means "i1 will be 1 and i2 will be 1" and "i1 will be 1 and i2 will be 2" respectively. It is not clear what you mean when you say "but next you will get 1, 1, 2" - there are only two variables, each of which holds exactly one value at a time. So you they can't together have three values.

Comment: Apologies for my bad question. The part I don't understand is where Asad says, "At each step, the value of i2 gets overwritten into i1, and the value that was stored in i2 gets incremented by the value stored in i1." Where is this CODE?  The CODE "i1, i2 = i2, i1+i2" => "1, 1, 2", right?

Comment: @macjeans `The CODE "i1, i2 = i2, i1+i2" => "1, 1, 2", right?` I don't understand what you mean by this. What is `=>` supposed to signify? This direction arrow and the three values you keep repeating don't make any sense to me. A variable can only have one value. You have two variables, there can only be two values in them, collectively.

Comment: @macjeans I'll try to explain this again. There are two variables: `i1` and `i2`. Initially they are given values of `1` and `1`, respectively. This is done using the first line in the function: `i1,i2 = 1,1`. Later, you start looping, and at each iteration of the loop, `i1` and `i2` are given values of `i2` and `i1 + i2`, respectively. This is done using the code: `i1, i2 = i2, i1+i2`.